# windows batch file change blank field to value

Tags: windows, batch-file, csv

I am writing a windows script to read in a txt file with 9 columns of data
I want to write this data out to a csv file to be loaded into a database.

I have found that one column is sometimes blank, so I would like to enter code 'rdp'
another column has mostly numbers, but for reason some values are a '.' (presumably indicating value less than 1. I would like to change these values to '0'

my code

```
  for /F %%b in (c:\ts_users\newfiles_list.txt) do (
      for /F "tokens=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9" %%i in (%%b) do (
        echo %%i,%%j,%%k,%%l,%%m,!idle!,%%o %%p,%%q >>%%~nb.csv
      )
    )
```

this manages to read in the txt file, then write it out as a csv.
column k is sometimes empty, column n sometimes has a '.'

I have tried variations of

```
    set var=rdp
    if %%k="" then set !k:=!var!
```

which doesnt work, so I a little stumped (after googling internet for days)

current input

```
201401241611 USERNAME              SESSIONNAME        ID  STATE   IDLE TIME  LOGON TIME eu1ptsw002  
201401241611 julie.noble           rdp-tcp#9           3  Active         18  24/01/2014 14:24 eu1ptsw002  
201401241611 svc.perfmon18                             7  Disc            3  24/01/2014 14:15 eu1ptsw002  
201401241611 reto.hofstetter                          10  Disc           40  24/01/2014 10:57 eu1ptsw002  
201401241611 lester.valentin                          14  Disc         1:16  24/01/2014 11:53 eu1ptsw002  
201401241611 philippe.bachmann                        15  Disc            2  24/01/2014 12:45 eu1ptsw002  
201401241611 patrik.soderlund      rdp-tcp#2          21  Active         24  24/01/2014 07:42 eu1ptsw002
```

current output

```
201401241611,USERNAME,SESSIONNAME,ID,STATE,,TIME LOGON,TIME 
201401241611,julie.noble,rdp-tcp#9,3,Active,,24/01/2014 14:24,eu1ptsw002 
201401241611,svc.perfmon18,7,Disc,3,,14:15 eu1ptsw002, 
201401241611,reto.hofstetter,10,Disc,40,,10:57 eu1ptsw002, 
201401241611,lester.valentin,14,Disc,1:16,,11:53 eu1ptsw002, 
201401241611,philippe.bachmann,15,Disc,2,,12:45 eu1ptsw002, 
201401241611,patrik.soderlund,rdp-tcp#2,21,Active,,24/01/2014 07:42,eu1ptsw002
```

required output

```
201401241611,USERNAME,SESSIONNAME,ID,STATE,,TIME LOGON,TIME 
201401241611,julie.noble,rdp-tcp#9,3,Active,18,24/01/2014 14:24,eu1ptsw002 
201401241611,svc.perfmon18,rdp,7,Disc,3,24/01/2014 14:15,eu1ptsw002 
201401241611,reto.hofstetter,rdp,10,Disc,40,24/01/2014 10:57,eu1ptsw002, 
201401241611,lester.valentin,rdp,14,Disc,1:16,24/01/2014 11:53,eu1ptsw002 
201401241611,philippe.bachmann,rdp,15,Disc,2,24/01/2014 12:45,eu1ptsw002 
201401241611,patrik.soderlund,rdp-tcp#2,21,Active,24,24/01/2014 07:42,eu1ptsw002
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include sample data featuring the errant lines and desired output version.

Comment: added sample data before and after running script

Comment: A single run of your posted code cannot produce your posted current output. The value of `!idle!` must be constant in your output since you do not change the value within the loop. But the 6th column in your output does not have a constant value.

Comment: The missing value in your 6th row cannot be due to a missing value in the source because consecutive spaces/tabs will collapse into a single delimiter. Also, that line is corrupted in multiple ways. The State is missing, and the date and time are split accross two columns, and last column is missing. I suspect your source file may have `!` within the content. Expansion of a FOR variable containing `!` will be corrupted.

Comment: Ive just rechecked, I think I got a bit mixed up between what I wanted and what Im actually getting, I have updated the current output above. Is there a way of uploading the input/output files - in case of the formatting is being lost in copy/pasting

Answer (score 4):

```
@echo off &setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
for /f "delims=" %%a in (file) do (
    set "line=%%~a"
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    set "line=!line:,.,=,0,!"
    set "line=!line:,,=,rdp,!"
    echo(!line!
    endlocal
)
```

Comment: Heh, heh, heh - word for word! :)

Comment: thank you, but I cant see that this is actually doing anything - output file looks the same as before running the script. the output file name is the same as the input filename?

Comment: @nyehus  , just add `>>temp.file` after the closing bracket and check the new file.That works perfectly and I shall delete my ans.

Comment: sorry I think Im being silly but I have added >>temp.file to the end of the above script, but all that appears to happen is a new file called temp.file is created with the names of the original input files in it.

Comment: @nyehus         `>>temp.file echo(!line!`

Comment: This would solve the question as posed by the OP. But it will not fix the problems! See my comments to the question.

Comment: the line set "line=!line:,,=,rdp,!" isnt changing anything, I have tried with various amounts of spaces, but still no luck

Comment: -1 because the answer doesn't explain anything about how to solve the problem. Also the OP uses tokens while the answer here goes through a different approach and despite it could be correct, it doesnt help anyone getting here having the same problem as the OP...